# How to uninstall node, eslint, prettier on macOS

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, prettier

I am using VSCode on a macOS. I installed node 2 years ago when doing an online  tutorial, but it never seemed to work. I have since installed eslint and prettier, and eslint doesn't work. Prettier works sometimes. After doing a bit of research , best solution seems to  be to uninstall and reinstall the lot in the root directory, as I didn't take enough care the first time. Question: Should I uninstall node before eslint and prettier? Also there seem to be 4 ways to uninstall node: using homebrew, NVM, Terminal and manually. Which is the best for a beginner? Will uninstalling node delete all instances of it?

Comment: This is not a programming question. You could ask this at https://superuser.com/ , make sure you've read their [help](https://superuser.com/help/asking) section before asking.

Comment: if you installed prettier and eslint with node, uninstall them first and then node. Just use any of the methods, see how it goes. I'd start with homebrew. Then I would search for places where node installs files/config and see if it was properly uninstalled. You can also just try installing the proper way after you attempt an uninstall and if it doesn't work, just keep working on the uninstall.

Comment: It's impossible to say because you haven't explained how you installed those apps. But your wording is concerning because you say "reinstall the lot in the root directory" which is wrong. You should be using a version manager like [asdf-vm](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html) with [asdf-nodejs](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-nodejs) which would install it in your *home* directory. Nothing related to Nodejs should ever be installed into the root directory (`/`) or by the root user (with `sudo`).

Comment: @Matthias: I have followed through your advice including manual removal, and then checked in the terminal`node -v` and got 'command not found' . Ditto for eslint and prettier, so I assume all 3 have been uninstalled. However my folders still have files like '.eslintrc.js' and '.eslintrc.json' and 'package-lock.json' . My question is, can I now delete these?

Comment: the eslintrc is just your previous settings, I would keep a backup but delete them (if you changed any nice settings) to see if it works without them. package-lock.json you definitely want to delete, it saves your current package configuration so that next time you do npm install it installs only what is in the package-lock. The file is then generated again if you remove it but then with whatever new packages/dependencies are in package.json.

Comment: in general, if you want to do a completely fresh install of something you are safe to delete all the files